# Show/hide rest of the rows when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `table` which has a `checkbox` in the first column (in a `<td>` element) of every `row`. When this is checked, the rest of the columns in that row will be displayed.

I have read several articles on this topic with some great examples but can't achieve exactly what I want. I had been able to hide the rest of the `<td>` elements using `css` but not been able to make it `visible`.

I understand this is possible with JavaScript but I am not well versed in it. Any help is highly appreciated.

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
}

table td {
  min-width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

table td lable {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.L3,
.L4,
.L5 {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Thank You Letter</th>
      <th>Pennant</th>
      <th>Trophy</th>
      <th>Medal</th>
      <th>Book Voucher</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <lable>Level 3</lable><input type="checkbox" name="level3" value="3" /></td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="tu3" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="pen3" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="trp3" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="med3" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="bkv3" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <lable>Level 4</lable><input type="checkbox" name="level4" value="4" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="tu4" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="pen4" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="trp4" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="med4" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="bkv4" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <lable>Level 5</lable><input type="checkbox" name="level5" value="5" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="tu5" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="pen5" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="trp5" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="med5" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="bkv5" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Seems a few missing words in my original post. They are: 'in a td', and 'rest of the tds'

Comment: This is not possible in pure CSS as it needs some programming logic. Why dont you use some JS instead? You dont have to be a JS pro to do simple thing like this.  Read this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: Look up how to run script on 'checked'. And for the css look up 'siblings' and related info. Update your question with some js after trying a few things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("tr td:first-child :checkbox").change(function() {
    var checkboxes = $(this).parent().siblings("td").children(":checkbox");
    var containers = $(this).parent().siblings("td:not(first-child)");
    if (this.checked) {
      containers.css('visibility', 'visible');
      checkboxes.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      containers.css('visibility', 'hidden');
      checkboxes.prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
}

table td {
  min-width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

table td lable {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.L3,
.L4,
.L5 {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="#">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Thank You Letter</th>
      <th>Pennant</th>
      <th>Trophy</th>
      <th>Medal</th>
      <th>Book Voucher</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <lable>Level 3</lable><input type="checkbox" name="level3" value="3" /></td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="tu3" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="pen3" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="trp3" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="med3" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="bkv3" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <lable>Level 4</lable><input type="checkbox" name="level4" value="4" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="tu4" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="pen4" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="trp4" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="med4" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="bkv4" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <lable>Level 5</lable><input type="checkbox" name="level5" value="5" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="tu5" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="pen5" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="trp5" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="med5" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="bkv5" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

**Using only JS:**

```js
var primaryCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll("tr td:first-child input[type=checkbox]");

Array.from(primaryCheckboxes).forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var secondaryCheckboxes = this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
    var checkedSatus = false,
      visibilityStatus = "hidden";

    if (this.checked) {
      checkedSatus = true;
      visibilityStatus = "visible";
    }

    Array.from(secondaryCheckboxes).forEach(checkbox => {
      if (checkbox !== this) {
        checkbox.checked = checkedSatus;
        checkbox.parentElement.style.visibility = visibilityStatus;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
}

table td {
  min-width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

table td lable {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.L3,
.L4,
.L5 {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Thank You Letter</th>
      <th>Pennant</th>
      <th>Trophy</th>
      <th>Medal</th>
      <th>Book Voucher</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <lable>Level 3</lable>
        <input type="checkbox" name="level3" value="3" />
      </td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="tu3" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="pen3" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="trp3" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="med3" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="L3"><input type="checkbox" name="bkv3" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <lable>Level 4</lable>
        <input type="checkbox" name="level4" value="4" />
      </td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="tu4" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="pen4" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="trp4" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="med4" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="bkv4" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <lable>Level 5</lable><input type="checkbox" name="level5" value="5" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="tu5" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="pen5" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="trp5" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="med5" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="bkv5" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Anurag, Thanks for your code and the details. However, its not about selecting all check-boxes. Perhaps my initial explanation wasn't clear enough. The idea is to keep all the check box columns hidden except the first one (as shown in the first line). Once the user selects the Year, only then the rest of the check-boxes will be visible and the user can then select the rest of the check boxes for each year. The first check box will work as toggle between show/hide. Thanks..

Comment: Hi Anurag, that was great. Thanks for all your time and effort. It works fine. Only that I wanted all the td elements hidden, when the page loads, except the first one. When a user selects the first check box, only then he has the rest of the check box options to select any of the gift items. But, I'm studying your JS code so that I can find a way to achieve that part. Thank you once again. :)